# My C++ File In Visual Studio 2022 Is Unable To Open A Png File For A Texture

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

So I tried to load an image from my CWD (current working directory) and I put the file (pyramid.png) in the same folder in which my C++ source file is located. Here is the code I was using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(512, 512), "SFML works.");
    sf::RectangleShape player(sf::Vector2f(100.0f, 100.0f));
    player.setPosition(206.0f, 206.0f);
    sf::Texture playerTexture;
    playerTexture.loadFromFile("pyramid.png");
    player.setTexture(&playerTexture);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event eveent;
        while (window.pollEvent(eveent))
        {
            switch (eveent.type) {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            }

            
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(player);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to run this code, my window kept crashing and the Debug console said:
[Debug message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSTW4.png)
Btw, I was using SFML 2.5.1 for this.

I tried searching on Google, but I couldn't find any solution that worked. Please help.

Comment: There is no guarantee that when the program runs the CWD is where the source is located. You can use a full path name instead of just the filname.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably that "pyramid.png" is not in the right place.

Visual Studio by default uses the project directory as the "working directory" when you run code from the IDE. You can change that in `<your project> Property Pages/Debugging/Working Directory`, but to just get your code to not crash, try an absolute path.

Also you should test the return value from `sf::Texture::loadFromFile` before setting the texture. It returns true if it succeeds according to the documentation.